# Does DBConnection/DBCommand use DTS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ado.net

I am getting the following error when trying to make a simple SQL call from one particular machine (VD5) to another machine (VD0):

"*Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed*"

The SQL is being executed via an old DBConnection/DBCommand object.

Strangely enough, this same code call works from another machine (VD2) to VD0.  When I use DTSPing utility to ping from VD5 to VD0, it takes 30 seconds!  When I DTSPing from VD2 to VD0, it takes less than a second.

Does DBConnection/DBCommand use DTS?  If I converted to SQLCommand would that avoid using DTS?

Also, any ideas of what could be causing the DTS slowness from VD5 to VD0?

Comment: Though I can't truly answer this question, I can almost guarantee you that the old non-specific connectors have to use some form of DTS to transform the data into a format they can handle. One that's more abstract. I would say just try it out and use the `SqlConnection` / `SqlCommand` objects instead.

Comment: Thanks Michael, like you, I'm suspecting that's the case.  I'll probably end up converting anyway, was more curious than anything.